# Missing } inserted in table where there is no need

Tags: tables, errors, overleaf, threeparttable, deluxetable

I have a somehow complex table that is the best way to get all I needed for it (data and footnotes and layout and all the rest). However, it is now giving me troubles for braces that do not exist. The error message (from overleaf) is :

```
Missing } inserted.

<inserted text> 
            }
l.497 }\enddata
           }
I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; 
then my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.
```

An extract from the table that returns the problem is the following:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{aastex62}
\usepackage{amsmath,amstext}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{apjfonts}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[switch]{lineno} 
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}

\begin{document}

\begin{longrotatetable}
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{deluxetable*}{lllccccclllc}
\tabletypesize{\scriptsize}
\tablecaption{A caption for this table.\label{tab:summary}}
\tablewidth{700pt}
\tabletypesize{\scriptsize}
\tablehead{
\colhead{Name} & \colhead{Type} & \colhead{Coor1} & \colhead{Coor2} & 
\colhead{C$_{sup}$} & \colhead{$C_{inf}$} & 
\colhead{S$_{\pi}^*$} & \colhead{S$_x$\,i} & 
\colhead{$t$} & \colhead{$i$}  & \colhead{$d^{\dagger}$}\\ 
\colhead{} & \colhead{} & \colhead{($^\circ$)} & \colhead{($^\circ$)} & 
\colhead{(s)} & \colhead{(s)} &
\colhead{(s)} & \colhead{(l-s)} & \colhead{($^\circ$)} & \colhead{} & \colhead{(kg)} } 
\startdata
\enddata
\end{deluxetable*}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{longrotatetable}

\end{document}
```

Obviously, I have the data between `\startdata` and `\enddata`, but I verified that the same error appears also when there is nothing in between. Why do I get the error?

Comment: We need more code. Where does `deluxetable` come from? Where does `longrotatetable` come from? There is a reason why everyone posting sniplets like this are asked to post a full minimal example instead.

Comment: What do you want to use the `threeparttable` package for? To insert table notes? If so and if you use the `aaastex63` documentclass (which I assume doue to your usage of `Deluxetable` and `longrotatetable`), use `\tablenotemark` and `\tablenotetext` commands as described in [section 2.16.5 Table End Notes  of the AASTeX v6.3 Author Guide](https://journals.aas.org/aastexguide/#table_end_notes)

Comment: MWE added. `tablenotemark` and `\tablenotetext` do not help in having the notes as I need them (below the long rotated table for each page - not just at the end of the table - and more details).

Comment: `threeparttable` only supports single page tables.

Comment: @leandriis does your comment mean that I should remove it ?

Comment: Removing the components related to `threeparttable` removes the error. Some style changes that can be made are related to using `\colhead{$C_{\text{sup}}$} & \colhead{$C_{\text{inf}}$} & \colhead{$S_{\pi}^*$} & \colhead{$S_x$\,i}`

Comment: @Leucippus, I would be glad to accept it if you can write an asnwer.

Comment: Multi-page tables are not the target of threeparttable, and it doesn't know about "deluxetable", but I don't know about threepartablex -- it seems to provide "notes in longtable".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By removing the package `threeparttablex`, and its two components used to wrap the table, the problem of `Missing }...` is removed. For the code given there remains one `warning` related to `Class revtex4-1` which is mentioned in the class file for the American Astronomical Society. The `aastex63` file says

> revtex4   : will produce an error message and demand to download revtex4-1.

The current version of `revtex` is `revtex4-2`. Fixing this amounts to changing a working class file and is best left for a future update of `aastex`.

By removing the main error components and making some subtle changes the code becomes:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{aastex63}
\usepackage{amsmath,amstext}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{apjfonts}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[switch]{lineno}


\begin{document}

\begin{longrotatetable}
\begin{deluxetable*}{lllccccclllc}
\tabletypesize{\scriptsize}
\tablecaption{A caption for this table. \label{tab:summary}}
\tablewidth{700pt}
\tabletypesize{\scriptsize}
\tablehead{
\colhead{Name} & \colhead{Type} & \colhead{Coor1} & \colhead{Coor2} &
\colhead{$C_{\text{sup}}$} & \colhead{$C_{\text{inf}}$} &
\colhead{$S_{\pi}^*$} & \colhead{$S_x$\,i} &
\colhead{$t$} & \colhead{$i$}  & \colhead{$d^{\dagger}$}\\
\colhead{} & \colhead{} & \colhead{($^\circ$)} & \colhead{($^\circ$)} &
\colhead{(s)} & \colhead{(s)} &
\colhead{(s)} & \colhead{(l-s)} & \colhead{($^\circ$)} & \colhead{} & \colhead{(kg)} 
}
\startdata
\enddata
\end{deluxetable*}
\end{longrotatetable}

\end{document}
```

It does appear that, currently, there is a bug in RevTex4-1 (and 2) that gives rise to a separate warning. See [RevTex4-2 error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/534295/class-revtex4-2-warning-failed-to-recognize)

Comment: Please add that the way (I used) to add notes one the same line at the end of the table (not the end of the page) was using `\tablenotemark{a}` where I want to put the note, and then `\begin{tablenotes}[flushright, para]
  \small\medskip` to add each user defined item with `\item[a]{\citet{Reference1};}`